# $l$-adic cohomology of hyperplane arrangements

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, l-adic-sheaves

Consider an arrangement of hyperplanes given by the faces of a simplex. Let's consider it as a scheme (a non-regular scheme) and let's also work over a finite field. Has the rational $l$-adic cohomology of this scheme with possible Tate twists been calculated? More precisely the $l$-adic cohomology of inverse system of sheaves given by $\mu_{l^m}^{\otimes n}$ (weight $n$). Working over the algebraic closure of finite fields is also fine.

More ambitiously how about semi-localization of the faces of the simplex on its vertices? is there some form of cohomological dimension for its cohomology which is based only on $n$?

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward computation (assuming $\ell$ is invertible, as usual). For instance, you could use the spectral sequence associated with the h-cover $\amalg_i X_i \to X$, where the $X_i$ are the components of $X$. The answer will be some combinatorial expression in the cohomology of $\mathbf Q_\ell(n)$ on $\mathbf P^{d-1}$, and will in some sense be 'the same' as in characteristic zero.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn So $l$-adic satisfied $h$ descent? Do you know a source for that? (note I am not talking about the Borel-Moore variant)

Comment: Ah, what I really want is cohomological descent for proper hypercoverings, which I suppose is a bit less than asking for full h-descent. For torsion étale sheaves, this is SGA IV$_2$, Exp. V$^{\text{bis}}$, Prop. 4.3.2. Note that the proof consists of *forward* references to VIII (effectiveness of descent data) and XII (proper base change theorem). Then take limits to get the $\ell$-adic case (I'm not aware of a reference, but this surely must be worked out somewhere...).

Comment: Calculating the cohomology of $\mu_{\ell^m}^{\otimes n}$ over the algebraic closure of any field is just the same as calculating the cohomology of $\mathbb Z/\ell^m$ and then tensoring with $\mu_{\ell^m}^{\otimes n}$. Is there a reason you've written it this way?

Comment: Are these affine or projective hyperplanes?

Comment: @WillSawin Right, I meant if over alg closed field if things is simpler educationally that would be fine too. Originally the field that I am working is not alg closed and I had the intention of thinking about continuous etale cohomology extended from finite type schemes, hence it couldn't get replaced by simpler sheaves. I was also thinking about affine simplex but I think the technique is going to be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the covering suggested by [R. van dobben de Bruyn](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454557/l-adic-cohomology-of-hyperplane-arrangements?noredirect=1#comment1176681_454557) is not just a proper hypercovering, but is even finite, there is something simpler one can do.

Let's work first over an algebraically closed field.

Let $i_k$ be the inclusion of the $k$'th hyperplane. Let $A$ be your coefficient ring. Then the map $A \to \bigoplus_{k=0}^n i_{k*} A$ extends to a long exact sequence $$A \to \bigoplus_{k=0}^n i_{k*} A \to \wedge^2 ( \bigoplus_{k=0}^n i_{k*} A) \to \wedge^3 ( \bigoplus_{k=0}^n i_{k*} A) \to\dots \to \wedge^{n+1} ( \bigoplus_{k=0}^n i_{k*} A ) $$ where the map $\wedge^m \to \wedge^{m+1}$ is given by wedging with a fixed global section of $\bigoplus_{k=0}^n i_{k*} A$.

Since each summand has rank $\leq 1$,  $\wedge^m ( \bigoplus_{k=0}^n i_{k*} A)$ is the sum over  $S \subseteq \{0,\dots, n\}$ of cardinality $n$ of $\bigotimes_{k\in S} i_{k* } A$, which is simply the constant sheaf supported on the intersection of the $k$ hyperplanes in $S$, which is a codimension $k$ affine space unless $S =\{0,\dots,n\}$ in which case it is empty. In particular, it has cohomology only in degree $0$.

So this resolution gives an acyclic resolution of $A$, so the cohomology of $A$ may be computed with this resolution, as the cohomology of the complex

$$  \bigoplus_{k=0}^n  A \to \wedge^2 ( \bigoplus_{k=0}^n  A) \to \wedge^3 ( \bigoplus_{k=0}^n  A) \to\dots \to \wedge^{n} ( \bigoplus_{k=0}^n i_{k*} A ) \to 0$$
with the map given by wedging with $(1,\dots, 1)$. This complex has cohomology $A$ in degree $0$ and $A$ in degree $n$, matching what we expect from a sphere.

Over a different base field, we would take Galois cohomology also. Over a finite field, we would potentially have cohomology in degrees $0,1, n,n+1$, depending on the Tate twist chosen.